# Anonymous Delegate Naming Convention

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, delegates

If I were to create an anonymous delegate such as:

```
  var x = new Func(x => x != null)
```

What is the result of:

```
  x.Method.FullName
```

What kind of naming convention does it follow?

Comment: Do you mean `var x = new Func<object,bool>(o => o != null);` and `x.Method.Name`?

Comment: Yes...........................

Comment: Why don't you try it your self?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell, the naming convention is something like 'method'__b'num'
where 'method' is the method which the anonymous method is declared in and 'num' is a numeric identifier.

Check out http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/149929/Under-the-hood-of-anonymous-methods-in-C